# Use Javascript function into Kendo Grid Template

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to use Javascript Function in Kendo Grid Create. 
For that I have defined the Javascript Function as,

```
<script>
    function GetCompanyID()
    {
        return $("#Company").val();
    }
</script>
```

And I want to use it in Create template of Kendo Grid as,

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Invoice.Models.ViewModels.DossierViewModel>()
    .Name("Dossier")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {


        columns.Bound(p => p.CustomerName).Title("Customer").Width(150);

        columns.Bound(p => p.InvoiceNumber).Title("INV no.").Width(100);//.Width(20);
        columns.Bound(p => p.InvoiceAmountLC).Title("INV Amount LC").Width(150);

    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text("Add New Dossier"))
    .Editable(ed => ed.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("New_Dossier"))                    //Having Different Template for New Dossier
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(10)
            .Model(model => { model.Id(p => p.DossierID); })
        .Read(read => read.Action("Dossier_Read", "Dossier"))
            .Create(create => create.Action("Dossier_Create", "Dossier", new { @CompanyID = GetCompanyID }))
            .Filter(filters =>
            {
                // Show products whose ProductName property contains "C"
                filters.Add(dossier => dossier.Status).Contains("");
            })
     )

)
```

In that I want to use that Javascript functio as I am currently using in Above code as,

```
.Create(create => create.Action("Dossier_Create", "Dossier", new { @CompanyID = GetCompanyID }))
```

But this is not the Way it should be used. Please Help me on this. How can I use that Javascript function into this, ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Data() method of the grid data source to send this data. Something like:

```
.Create(create => create.Action("Dossier_Create", "Dossier").Data("GetCompanyID")

function GetCompanyID()
{
    return {
      CompanyID: $("#Company").val();
    };
}
```

Check the grid [FAQ](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq#how-do-i-send-values-to-my-action-method-when-binding-the-grid?) for more info and an example.